# Change List<SomeType> to Dictionary<string, SomeType> but maintain compatibility

Tags: c#, serialization, dictionary

We have the following code in production and it is being used in JSON serialization/deserialization (serialized lists of SomeType in files on hard drive):

```
public sealed class Cultures : List<Culture>
{
}
```

The requirements have changed in a way that we would benefit greatly if we had it implemented like `Dictionary<string, Culture>` because than we get key/value functionality (`Culture` class has a property `ID` of type `string` which would be used as a key). Staying with `List` we have to do this manually.

What's the best (or only, if any) way to go to Cultures : Dictionary but keep serialization working even with those files that already have a List of Cultures serialized in them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the interface [IDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s4ys34ea.aspx) on your Cultures class. You can use it as a dictionary, but all serialization works as before.

Answer (score 1):

Change the property and customize the serialization to support the old format. If you are using json.net, use the [JonConverter] attribute.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep your list and add a converter method using *LINQ*.

```
public sealed class Cultures : List<Culture>
{
  public Dictionary<string, Culture> ToDictionary()
  {
    return this.ToDictionary(_=>_.Id);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[CollectionDataContract]
public sealed class Cultures : Dictionary<string, Culture>
{
}
```